# Filter for values if specific XML structure passes

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x

I have an XML that looks like this (has a lot of values):

```
<gml:interior>
    <gml:LinearRing>
      <gml:posList srsDimension="3" count="7">253602.645 593015.808 0.0 253603.97 593021.537 0.0 253611.953 593019.691 0.0 253609.047 593007.125 0.0 253603.484 593008.412 0.0 253605.065 593015.248 0.0 253602.645 593015.808 0.0</gml:posList>
    </gml:LinearRing>
  </gml:interior>
  <gml:exterior>
    <gml:LinearRing>
      <gml:posList srsDimension="3" count="9">253630.858 593000.326 0.0 253629.502 592994.829 0.0 253627.382 592995.352 0.0 253625.6 592988.13 0.0 253614.622 592990.839 0.0 253616.723 592999.355 0.0 253621.946 592998.067 0.0 253622.983 593002.269 0.0 253630.858 593000.326 0.0</gml:posList>
    </gml:LinearRing>
  </gml:exterior>
```

In a python project I get the "gml:posList" values and put them in a list:

```
from lxml import etree as ET

tree = ET.parse("/Users/Admin/jm.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
building_list=[]

# XML is using gml formatting
for a in root.findall('.//{http://www.opengis.net/gml}posList'):
    building_list.append([a.text])

building_list
```

I only want "posList" values when they are inside "gml:exterior" brackets not when they are in "gml:interior". How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following XPath instead:

```
.//{http://www.opengis.net/gml}exterior//{http://www.opengis.net/gml}posList
```